# Publishing to Artifactory using Grail's gradlew and a user's gradle.properties file

Tags: grails, gradle

I'm trying to publish to Artifactory using the project's Gradle wrapper and credentials keyed into the user's gradle.properties.

In my `build.gradle` file, I have the following snippet to publish to `Artifactory`:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "https://path.to/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'plugins-release-local'
            username = ${artifactory_user}
            password = ${artifactory_password}
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of my `gradle.properties` file:

```
me@workstation ~/.gradle
$ cat gradle.properties
artifactory_user=xxx
artifactory_password=yyy
```

With the username and password hard coded in `build.gradle`, this works:

```
./gradlew artifactoryPublish
```

While attempting to read from the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
./gradlew artifactoryPublish
HTTP response code: 502. HTTP response message: Bad Gateway
```

While Attempting to pass the credentials via the CLI:

```
./gradlew -Dartifactory_user=xxx -Dartifactory_password=yyy artifactoryPublish
HTTP response code: 401. HTTP response message: Unauthorized
```

**Update #1**

Update  of build.gradle per @RaGe:

```
artifactory {
    contextUrl = "https://path/to/artifactory"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'plugins-release-local'
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
            maven = true

        }
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Result: getting a 401 instead of a 502 using:

- ./gradlew artifactoryPublish
- ./gradlew -Dartifactory_user=xxx -Dartifactory_password=yyy artifactoryPublish

**Update #2**

Artifactory runs on Tomcat8/Java8 accessed through a reverse proxy on Apache 2.2.

**Update #3**

Note to solution: under Cygwin, make sure to edit the right gradle.properties, located in C:\Users\username.gradle\gradle.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a syntax issue. remove the `${}` around your variables.

```
username = artifactory_user
password = artifactory_password
```

Comment: I've been going back and forth, confirming the credentials from my gradle.properties file and hard coding the values in my build.gradle. When I hard code the values, it works all the time. Otherwise, I get the 401.

Comment: did you try the syntax I suggested?

Comment: hmm, maybe print `artifactory_user` and password to see what values are being picked up from gradle.properties?

Comment: Used println and it wasn't right credentials. Furthermore, I was modifying the wrong gradle.properties. Under cygwin, it's under c:\users\me\.gradle\gradle.properties.

Comment: For Cygwin, that's what I've been using for my Grails development (SDKMan + Grails 3.1.1 + NetBeans 8) recently... unsure about the -D not working.